# CakePHP 2.0 authentication(login) without ctp files but other types

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, phptal

Here, [A COMPLETE LOGIN AND AUTHENTICATION APPLICATION TUTORIAL FOR CAKEPHP 2.3](http://miftyisbored.com/a-complete-login-and-authentication-application-tutorial-for-cakephp-2-3/) I got some hints to build the authentication functionality.

I am now using [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/) which use html instead of ctp files.
Is there anyone who use the html files to cooperate with Cake's authentication?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

**login.html**[view]

```
<form method="POST" tal:attributes="action string:/users/login">
   <input type="text" name="username" size="15" maxlength="30" placeholder="your email" /><br />
   <input type="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="15" placeholder="password" /><br />
    input type="submit" value="log in" />
</form>
```

**UsersController.php**[controller]

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler',
        'Auth' => array(
                'authenticate' => array(
                        'Form' => array('userModel' => 'User',
                                'fields' => array('username' => 'email',
                                        'password' => 'password'))),
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display',
                        'landing'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'new_boards', 'action' => 'login'),
                'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display',
                        'landing'),
                'authError' => 'Input youer email and password correctly, please',));`

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('login', 'logout', 'viewUser', 'showHome');

    if ($this->Session->check('User.100000001.id')) {
        $this->current_user_id = $this->Session->read('User.100000001.id');
    } else {
        $this->current_user_id = 100000001;
    }
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {// failed here
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('wrong email or password'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

But I have not create an user table in my db, is this the problem?

Comment: When you google for it you find: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dkvasnicka/2007/04/24/using-phptal-for-templates-phptalview-class It is quite old, but the basic idea might still be valid. I would, personally, see if phptal couldnt work with .ctp files instead. would be cleaner IMO.

Comment: @mark Yes, I refers the exactly article for my implementation;) But that is just how to integrate PHPTAL into Cake but no any authentication mentioned. I am here want to know how to integrate Cake's authentication (from the front-end form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just now for more than two month looking over.

See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/XuuvukmZSgc) at Google Group Discussion, which I replied just now.

Good luck to those who have the similar issue!

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP by default supports ctp files as its view files. If you want to use any other extension for your view files you can simple change it in your Controller or AppController file. Look at thye below code:

```
public $ext = '.php';

Mention it in your Controller or AppController file.
```

Comment: Yes, I know this and have changed to html extension and it is working. What I want to know is that because it seems Cake's authentication have to cooperate with its own view component such as __form__. If I can not let the form to work  correctly, I think the authentication would not work, either.

Comment: That should not be a problem I guess, are you facing such problem?

Comment: It seems to be problem as it always failed when executing `if ($this->Auth->login())...`. So I think maybe it is not compatible with Cake's default authentication rule:<